# How can I get buttons to move when I sort a list?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with buttons for each row of data. One column contains values that can be sorted in ascending order and another column contains a filter that can filter out rows by name. When I run my Sort and Filter macro that accomplishes both of these tasks, the button visibly remains in the same row, but when I click the button to do specific tasks based on the button's row it has moved. I am really lost with this one so I'll include the code that sorts and filters data, along with the code that gets the clicked button's row and column. The buttons' properties are set to move and size with the cell. The button turns a dark grey when its row address has changed for some reason. I have looked around and can't seem to find a solution to this problem... Sorry if I missed something somewhere and thanks in advance for the help.

Code for identifying clicked button's row and column...

```
Dim b  As Object

Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)

With b.TopLeftCell
    task_row = .Row
    button_col = .Column
End With
```

Code that sorts and filters rows...

```
Sub Filter_List()
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(start_data_row - 1, 1), Cells(start_data_row +   num_tasks - 1, last_col)).AutoFilter _
        Field:=name_col, Criteria1:=task_owner
End Sub

Sub Sort_List()
    Range(Cells(start_data_row, 1), Cells(start_data_row + num_tasks - 1, last_col)).Sort _
        key1:=Range(Cells(start_data_row, days_left_col), Cells(start_data_row, days_left_col)), _
        order1:=xlAscending
    Worksheets(sht_name).Range(Cells(start_data_row - 1, days_left_col), Cells(start_data_row + num_tasks - 1, days_left_col)).AutoFilter _
        Field:=days_left_col, Criteria1:="<" & max_days, Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

Comment: Why dont you change the button to not move or size with cells. This way it is always stationary and you can manipulate it better if you need to.

Comment: It needs to move with the row of data it corresponds with.

Comment: If it is just one button, why does its position matter so much? If it is one button for each line of data (if yes, how many? And do they all do the same thing, but to different lines of data?) then you should probably rethink how to accomplish what it is they do.

Comment: There are close to one thousand lines of data with a button for each line. They all do the same thing but to different lines of data. I agree that having a button on each line doesn't make sense, but the person I am building the spreadsheet for wants it that way.

Comment: Hyperlinks are easier to manage than buttons if data could be sorted or filtered.

Comment: I'd tell the person that wants it that way that this is Excel, not some web application. Go with `=HYPERLINK` formulas, not thousands of on-sheet controls... that's... pretty much *begging* for the book to get corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use all those buttons, why not use a Private Sub based on a cell selection – especially if, as you say, the same code is run (albeit for different lines) irrespective of which button is clicked?  The following sub works if any cell in column A in the used range is selected.  Just put your code where I suggest – then you can dispense with all the buttons.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    If Not Intersect(Range("A1:A" & LastRow), Target) Is Nothing Then

      ‘Put your generic code here

    End If

End Sub
```